How to implement a model input to cope with model.predict([10.0]) in tensorflow 2.13
I've tried everything but cannot get a tensorflow simple linear regression model to take a single element list.
Due to the circumstances, I cannot do any preprocessing or wrap it in a numpy array, the model must cope with:
model.predict([10.0])
